# Why is (a % 256) different than (a & 0xFF)?

Tags: c++, optimization

I always assumed that when doing `(a % 256)` the optimizer would naturally use an efficient bitwise operation, as if I wrote `(a & 0xFF)`.

When testing on compiler explorer gcc-6.2 (-O3):

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int mod(int num) {
    return num % 256;
}

mod(int):
    mov     edx, edi
    sar     edx, 31
    shr     edx, 24
    lea     eax, [rdi+rdx]
    movzx   eax, al
    sub     eax, edx
    ret
```

And when trying the other code:

```
// Type your code here, or load an example.
int mod(int num) {
    return num & 0xFF;
}

mod(int):
    movzx   eax, dil
    ret
```

Seems like I'm completely missing something out.
Any ideas?

Comment: 0xFF is 255 not 256.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: So? `%` is not `&` either.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: I am sure the OP is very much aware of that. They're used with different operations.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje: That was my explanation initially. I even answered. But the OP is using different operators.

Comment: Out of interest, do you get better results if `num` is `unsigned`?

Comment: Elad, it looks to me the first conversion attempts to preserve the sign. Try with `unsigned int`. Also, `movzx` to extract a byte out of a longer unit is *extremely* efficient – it might even be a special case. So try with another number such as `512`/`0x1ff`.

Comment: Yep. Actually with unsigned int it optimizes. Nice...

Comment: @RishikeshRaje Bitwise and 0xFF is equivalent to modulo 2^8 for unsigned integers.

Comment: Note that modulo sign is handled differently by different languages. For example `(-7) % 256 == 177` in Python because in Python the remainder has the same sign of the second argument of the modulo (which mean `-79 % -256 == -79`). C chose a different rule for the signs (which is mathematically less elegant...).

Comment: Related: Eric Lippert's great article on the difference between Remainder and Modulus (its examples are in C#, but really it's about a lot of languages): https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/05/whats-the-difference-remainder-vs-modulus/

Comment: @Bakuriu: And in Python's case, optimizing `x % 256` to `x & 255` would indeed be valid.

Comment: If you look closely at the generated assembly, it *is* using an efficient bitwise operation. Just not the one you expected. :)

Comment: Rule of thumb:  bitwise operations should be done only on unsigned integral types.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Outside of those rare cases where one would actually need to compute a negative remainder, what approach would you suggest for computing "x mod 256" if not "x & 255" in cases where x might be negative?  Coercing to unsigned and using the remainder operator might work, but it would obscure the reliance upon having a power-of-two modulus [e.g. "-1 mod 3" should be 2, but (-1 % 3u) will yield 0 on any machine where unsigned has an even number of bits.]

Comment: @supercat:  I don't quite follow your question.  For portability, you cannot assume a signed integer uses two's complement--it could, in theory, be sign magnitude.  Any bitwise operation you apply to a signed int that might change the sign bit puts you in the realm of undefined behavior.  If you want the bottom eight bits of `x`, you'd best cast `x` to unsigned first:  `static_cast<unsigned int>(x) & 0xFF`.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy: Are there any conforming C99 or later implementations for sign-magnitude or ones'-complement machines?  If any exist, I'd be curious how they handle the "long long" type.  Hardware which can support efficient arithmetic on multi-word operators can also support efficient two's-complement math, so if hardware can't efficiently support two's-complement math the only way it could handle "long long" would be if it used 64-bit words.  Has any one's-complement or sign-magnitude machine ever had a word size that large?

Comment: @supercat:  This seems to be venturing off topic.  Perhaps you should post a new question.

Comment: @RishikeshRaje so? x & (2^N-1) = x % (2^N)

Comment: @Bakuriu: Is that really true, because -7 mod 256 should be 249 if the result is supposed to be positive.

Comment: @Erik That's a typo. It should be `(-79) % 256`, which is the same value mentioned later in that comment. I guess I chose that number because it's mentioned in the accepted answer, but I typoed it

Comment: I realized that as soon as I posted. Which only cements the adamant; you should always look again. Preferably before posting.

Answer (score 231, accepted):

It's not the same. Try `num = -79`, and you will get different results from both operations. `(-79) % 256 = -79`, while `(-79) & 0xff` is some positive number.

Using `unsigned int`, the operations are the same, and the code will likely be the same.

**PS-** Someone commented

> They shouldn't be the same, `a % b` is defined as `a - b * floor (a / b)`.

That's not how it is defined in C, C++, Objective-C (ie all the languages where the code in the question would compile).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127852/discussion-on-answer-by-gnasher729-why-is-a-256-different-than-a-0xff).

Answer (score 55):

### Short answer

`-1 % 256` yields `-1` and not `255` which is `-1 & 0xFF`. Therefore, the optimization would be incorrect.

### Long answer

C++ has the convention that `(a/b)*b + a%b == a`, which seems quite natural. `a/b` always returns the arithmetic result without the fractional part (truncating towards 0). As a consequence, `a%b` has the same sign as `a` or is 0.

The division `-1/256` yields `0` and hence `-1%256` must be `-1` in order to satisfy the above condition (`(-1%256)*256 + -1%256 == -1`). This is obviously different from `-1&0xFF` which is `0xFF`. Therefore, the compiler cannot optimize the way you want.

The relevant section in the [C++ standard [expr.mul §4] as of N4606](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4606.pdf) states:

> For integral operands the `/` operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded; if the quotient `a/b` is representable in the type of the result, `(a/b)*b + a%b` is equal to `a` [...].

### Enabling the optimization

However, **using `unsigned` types, the optimization would be completely correct**, satisfying the above convention:

```
unsigned(-1)%256 == 0xFF
```

See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Performance_issues).

### Other languages

This is handled very different across different programming languages as you can look up on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 50):

Since C++11, `num % 256` has to be non-positive if `num` is negative.

So the bit pattern would depend on the implementation of signed types on your system: for a negative first argument, the result is not the extraction of the least significant 8 bits.

It would be a different matter if `num` in your case was `unsigned`: these days I'd almost *expect* a compiler to make the optimisation that you cite.

Comment: Almost but not quite. If `num` is negative, then `num % 256` is zero or negative (a.k.a. non-positive).

Comment: @Nayuki: Yes, non-positive is more precise. Thank you. I've amended.

Comment: Which IMO, is a mistake in the standard: mathematically modulo operation should take the sign of the divisor, 256 in this case. In order to understand why consider that `(-250+256)%256==6`, but `(-250%256)+(256%256)` must be, according to the standard, "non-positive", and therefore not `6`. Breaking associativity like that has real life side effects: for example when computing "zooming out" rendering in integer coordinates one has to shift the image to have all coordinates non-negative.

Comment: @Michael Modulus has never been distributive over addition ("associative" is the wrong name for this property!), even if you follow the math definition to the letter. For example, `(128+128)%256==0` but `(128%256)+(128%256)==256`. Perhaps there's a good objection to the specified behavior, but it isn't clear to me that it's the one you said.

Comment: @DanielWagner, you are right, of course, I misspoke with "associative". However, if one keeps the sign of the divisor and computes everything in modular arithmetic, the distributive property does hold; in your example you would have `256==0`. The key is to have exactly `N` possible values in modulo `N` arithmetic, which is only possible if all the results are in the range `0,...,(N-1)`, not `-(N-1),...,(N-1)`.

Comment: @Michael `256==0` in exactly the same sense that `-6==250`.

Comment: @DanielWagner, the range of `x%256` is different. That matters in applications.

Comment: @Michael the identity that's always satisfied is if `q = n / d; r = n % d` then `n == q * d + r`. If `/` is *truncating* division `r` has to be sometimes negative. Only if `/` rounds to negative infinity can `r` be always nonnegative. Older standards permitted either behavior, but the current ones for both C and C++ require truncating division and so also require negative mods. Fixing it up to the other behavior, is, of course, trivial now that you know which one you'll get.

Comment: @Michael: Except % is not a modulo operator, it's a *remainder* operator.

Comment: @Michael: A lot of code expects to apply compensation to the result of many languages' broken division and so-called-modulus operators; fixing the operators to use the more helpful mathematical rules would break a lot of such code.

Comment: @Joren - Indeed.  And more specifically, it's the remainder operator *for division with truncation towards zero*, which is the operation performed by C or C++'s `/` operator on integer operands.  For division with truncation to negative infinity (which some people prefer) the remainder operation always yields positive results and *is* the same as the bitwise operation suggested in the question.

Answer (score 11):

I don't have telepathic insight into the compiler's reasoning, but in the case of `%` there is the necessity of dealing with negative values (and division rounds towards zero), while with `&` the result is always the lower 8 bits.

The `sar` instruction sounds to me like "shift arithmetic right", filling up the vacated bits with the sign bit value.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out:

If you like me want the modulo operation to actually output a positive integer, as in my use case where I convert a hue (hsv color space) double where 1.0 == 360 degrees to a unsigned char by multiplying with 255.0, taking the floor followed by modulo 256. Then &0xff is a correct optimization. Observe that I treat 255 as 360 degrees to fit into unsigned char in my case.

```
hue = [-1.0 , 2.0]
hue = (unsigned char)(floor(hue * 255.0) & 0xff)
```

But this might not be the right solution for your specific use case.